# Java bmp from Databbase

Tags: java, database, bmp

I need to create a BMP (bitmap) image from a database using Java. The problem is that I have huge sets of integers ranging from 10 to 100.

I would like to represent the whole database as a bmp. The amount of data 10000x10000 per table (and growing) exceeds the amount of data I can handle with int arrays.

Is there a way to write the BMP directly to the hard drive, pixel by pixel, so I don't run out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

A file would work (I definitely woudln't do a per pixel call, you'll be waiting hours for the result). You just need a buffer. Break the application apart along the lines of ->

```
int[] buffer = new int[BUFFER_SIZE];

ResultSet data = ....;  //Forward paging result set

while(true)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
  {
    //Read result set into buffer

  }
  //write buffer to cache (HEAP/File whatever)

  if(resultSetDone)
    break;
}
```

Read the documentation on your database driver, but any major database is going to optimize your ResultSet object so you can use a cursor and not worry about memory.

All that being said... an int[10000][10000] isn't why you're running out of memory. Its probably what you're doing with those values and your algorithm. Example:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    int[][] ints = new int[10000][];

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Start");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      ints[i] = new int[10000];
      for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        ints[i][j] = i*j % Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;

      System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(ints[500][999]) + " <- value");

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Stop");
  }

}
```

Output ->

```
1344554718676 Start
//not even listing this
249750 <- value
1344554719322 Stop
```

Edit--Or if I misinterpreted your question try this ->
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/LoadimagefromDerbydatabase.htm

I see... well take a look around, I'm rusty but this seems to be a way to do it. I'd double check my buffering...

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    // 2 ^ 24 bytes, streams can be bigger, but this works...
    int size = Double.valueOf((Math.floor((Math.pow(2.0, 24.0))))).intValue();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      bytes[i] = (byte) (i  % 255);

    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); 

    File file = new File("test.io"); //kill the hard disk

    //Crappy error handling, you'd actually want to catch exceptions and recover
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
    try
    {
      //You do need to check the buffer as it will have crap in it on the last read
      out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
      while(in.available() > 0)
      {
        int total = in.read(buffer);
        out.write(buffer, 0, total);
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      if(out != null)
        try
        {
          out.flush();
          out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Start");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(bytes[bytes.length - 1]) + " <- value");
    System.out.println("File size is-> " + file.length());
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Stop");
  }
}
```

Comment: "Edit--Or if I misinterpreted your question... " Funny but no. You are exactly on what im trying here. The problem the 10000 2D int[] is a 400000000byte RAM usage. I do have more ram than that but i dont know how large the tables will get in the end. Can you give me some code on how to actually write the buffer to my File so that the outcome will be a bmp.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that tomorrow... almost 5am at my place

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as a file, which is conceptually just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: How do i get them bmp out of that file then? ... Its stored inside a database already. Im kinda stupid here i guess